# Copy range to another sheet last row

Tags: excel, vba

In sheet3 (c6:h6) data will get updated in 3 min.

I need to copy this data to another sheet4 (b6:G6) last row.

Error is coming in "Range("b1").End(xlDown).Offset(1, 0).Select"

```vb
Sub test()

Workbooks("nifty1.xlsm").Activate
Sheet3.Select
Range("c6:h6").Copy

Sheet4.Select
Range("b1").End(xlDown).Offset(1, 0).Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
Application.CutCopyMode = False

Application.OnTime Now + TimeValue("00:03:10"), "test"
End Sub
```

Comment: This error will be produced if column B is empty. use `Range("B1000000").End(xlUp).Offset(1,0).Select` instead

Comment: Avoid Select & Activate.... `With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet4"): Workbooks("nifty1.xlsm.xlsm").Worksheets("Sheet3").Range("C6:H6").Copy Destination:=.Cells(.Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Offset(1): End With`.  The `:` in the code is used in place of a new line.  Sheet tabs are named Sheet4 and Sheet3 rather than using the sheet codename.

Answer (score 1):

You could try:

```
With Workbooks("nifty1.xlsm")
    .Sheet3.Range("c6:h6").Copy
    .Sheet4.Range("B" & .Sheet4.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
End With

Application.CutCopyMode = False

Application.OnTime Now + TimeValue("00:03:10"), "test"
```

Please, read [How to avoid using Select in Excel VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba)

Comment: The sheet code names are meant to be used as they are, without a qualifier e.g. `Sheet3`. They refer to sheets in the workbook containing the code (`ThisWorkbook`) which in this case, due to lack of information, is only likely to be the `nifty1.xlsm` workbook.